# Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

I use this package `video_player: ^0.10.4+1`.

In particular video, the project throws this exception :

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError
, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: 
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available 
extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor,
 AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor)
 could read the stream., null)
```

Also, other videos work correctly.

how to fix this exception and make the video work?